# How can I "experience" that my S3 object is encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In uploaded a txt file to S3 and enable S3 server side encryption. This appears to have worked. Yet I wonder whether there is anyway to "experience" it. Any approach that I took, AWS decrypted my object (for example when I downloaded it, or even accessed the public URL from a different computer).

What is the scenario in which S3 does **not** decrypt the object? I.e. what is it protecting me from? Can I (easily) create such a situation (i.e. somehow try to access the object with S3 refusing to decrypt it for me)?

Comment: Yes, a role that has S3 full access but no KMS access will be denied access to the object because S3 cannot decrypt the object because the role cannot access the relevant key. Alternatively you could open up the bucket to the entire world by enabling public access and see that a browser will still not be able to view it because KMS key access is not granted to the public.

Comment: well, access denied sounds good to me :)

Comment: indeed! please post this as an answer